# jQuery to find URI in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a script that runs on every page of my codeigniter site.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Cufon.replace('h1');
    $('#term').hint();

    setTimeout('changeImage()',9000);
});
```

I only want that last line `setTimeout('changeImage()',9000);` if I'm on the base url and there are no segments in the URI (only want this to run on my homepage).

Is this possible to do some type of `if` statement with jQuery and find out if there are no segments in the URI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

```
if ( window.location == YOUR_BASE_URL ) {
    setTimeout('changeImage()',9000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do this with simple javascript using window.location, you have three things to worry about: pathname, search and hash, the code will be something like:

```
var win_location = window.location;
if ( win_location.pathname === "" || win_location.pathname === "/" && win_location.hash === "" && win_location.search === "")
{
   // I'M HOME NOW DO SOMETHING
} 
// hash will be for things like #anchor in the url
// search will be for things like ?param1=john&param2=doe
// so if you need those for some kind of dynamic handling on the home page remove the
// matching condition
```